# Report Builder Query

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder

How to display a table in separate pages for each multivalued parameters in Report Builder?
For example : If I have chosen 2 values of a parameter ,i.e., A and B , then the data table for parameter A should be displayed in first page and B should be displayed in the next page.

Comment: Add a row group that groups by the column containing the values ('A' and 'B') then on the row group properties set the page breaks to 'between each instance'

Comment: Thanks Alan, its working.